# how does childNode indexing work with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes, dom-manipulation

For example, if I have

```
              <div>
                <h2>Name</h2>
                <h3>age</h3>
                <span class='fa fa-trash'></span>
             </div>
```

and when clicking the span (icon) I say

```
this.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText
```

it would target the Name but if I say

```
this.parentNode.childNodes[2].innerText
```

it would not target Age. why is this? Is there a resource that explains this well? I know the indexing doesn't start at 0 but I don't understand how the indexing work.

Comment: i think you're thinking of `node.children[]`, which doesn't include whitespace nodes. The index starts at `0` by the way, so `childNodes[1]` hits `Name` because it's the 2nd child node, after the whitespace run of the line break in the HTML. `Name` is the zero-th element of `children`, while `age` is the `[1]` and the icon is the `[2]` index...

Comment: @dandavis has it right, but to elaborate a little more: the indexing is from 0, but [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) includes *all* [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)s, including in particular [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text), which includes any characters not included in HTML elements - and this includes whitespace.

Comment: As a result, in your HTML the div has 7 childNodes, of which the odd-numbered ones (those with even indices: 0,2,4,6) are textNodes containing whitespace, while indices 1, 3 and 5 are the elements you care about. You could easily see this yourself by logging the whole of the `childNodes` array.

Comment: yeah, childNodes has been confusing devs for 25 years. Just use `children` and forget about `childNodes`, you hardly ever need to use it...

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I appreciate that. I honestly could've just logged it to see myself, Robin. You are right.

Comment: You can get the behavior you expect if you use IE7 or below. However this behavior is non-standard. All standard browsers are fully text preserving. Therefore `childnode[0]` is the newline and space/tabs before the `<h2>` and `childnodes[2]` is the newline and spaces/tabs after the `<h2>`

Answer (score 1):

DOM is not just the elements you see in your HTML code. In-between each element is a "text node" where text can be displayed. An example of this would be having text in a div below a a header. So...

```
<div>
    <!-- Index 0: Text node -->
    <h1>Header Text</h1> <!-- Index 1: Element -->
    Description Text <!-- Index 2: Text node -->
</div>
```

As you can see, you are allowed to insert text in the `div` without wrapping it in an element. These are called text nodes which you see when you put the text in normal text elements (such as `span` or `p`) or buttons (`<button>TEXT</button>`). So to get around this in you JavaScript code, you could either do it the lazy way;

```
document.getElementById("ELEMENT_ID").childNodes[INDEX*2 + 1]
```

or by using the `children` property;

```
document.getElementById("ELEMENT_ID").children[INDEX]
```

The problem with this method is that it only returns 'element' children within the div, so the description text in the above HTML example will not be accessible. (`[H1]` instead of `[Text, H1, Text]`), but I suppose that is what you're looking for anyway. :)